# Java: Resolve method's generic type at runtime

Tags: java, methods, reflection, static-methods, reflections

How can I resolve this method's generic type at runtime?

My method signature: `static <T> T get(String key)`

The method must remain static.

Comment: post whole code block here for get help

Comment: This code is equivalent to just returning `Object`, the generics really do nothing here.  I'd ask why you want to do this, what's the goal?

Comment: @markspace the point is to use it as a boilerplate-free preferences or attributes system, where I can for example have an inferred type of boolean in such a case: `if (Prefs.get("isActive"))` or for example `int saveTime = Prefs.get("saveTime");`

Comment: The goal is to eliminate the need for a `getOrDefault` method and instead calculate the default value for `T` without needing a direct argument of `T`.

Comment: Java can't resolve methods based on return type.  It uses parameter types and method names only, so I don't think what you are envisioning is going to work.

Comment: Generics are a compile-time illusion there to help enforce stronger type-safety and prevent the need for explicit casts. There is no way to resolve a generic type at runtime as far as I know, seeing how they don't even exist in bytecode

Answer (score -3):

Like this:
(Hibernate code)

```
public class XXXDao<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    private Class<T> getEntityClass() {
        if (entityClass == null) {
            entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
        return entityClass;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This example resolves the generic type of a class and does not work due to `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`

Comment: Anyway, static <T> T get(String key) method cannot determine the T class type. If you want, you must add a input parameter, like this: static <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, String key)